# Sql count query always return 1

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-spark-sql

I'm using this query to find out the percentage of female employees. But somehow, when I combine that operation in one query like the one below, it always returns 1.0.

However, if I query separately and divide it, it's proper. I think I'm messing up with some syntax here.

What am I doing wrong?

`employees` and `citizens` are two tables.

```
SELECT (count(e.name)/count(c.name))
from citizens as c, employees as e
where c.gender=false and e.gender=false
```

Comment: Percentages are floating point numbers. CAST one of the count results into a floating point or multiply one of them by 1.0 before doing your division.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're simply creating a cross product between the rows in the two tables, and then counting the number of rows in the resulting cross product. You need to use separate queries to calculate each count:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees WHERE gender = false)/
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM citizens WHERE gender = false)
```

Comment: Got it. I thought it must have been the cross product because when I select-ed names instead of their count-s, it was almost all to all mappings!

Answer (score 0):

You're getting 1 because count returns integers.You need to cast them to floats so that you can get percentage. Also, only casting the numerator is enough in this case.This will return quotient in floats.

```
SELECT cast(count(e.name)as float)/count(c.name)
from citizens as c, employees as e
where c.gender=false and e.gender=false;
```

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.